# How to get and handle ros-industrial errors in a generic way?

Tags: ros, ros-industrial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I want to know if there is a way to get the error in a common way for ros-industrial robots, independently of the robot I use.

My actual project may use different kind of robots that's why we decided to use ROS-I, to communicate by the same way.
The problems begin when I have to deal with errors.
Example:
On the Universal-robot, the robot may stop because of the "protective lock", but on the Kuka they may be others.
I actually can get the protective error by subscribing on /rosout, and filter message by name and message (but as I filter by name "/ur_driver", it's not generic).

The second problem it implies is how to handles them ? For the UR "protective lock", the only solution I found was to send a socket command to it's dashboard interface, but again, it's not generic.

Did you know how can I handle all these kind of errors in a generic way ? Or is that unsupported by ROS-industrial interfaces and I have to deal with each type of error, for each robot we want to use ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/272869/how-to-get-and-handle-ros-industrial-errors-in-a-generic-way-?/) by [matEhickey](https://answers.ros.org/users/31791/matehickey/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2017-10-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [matEhickey](https://answers.ros.org/users/31791/matehickey/) on 2017-10-12**:
Also, sort of same question for the robot state ? Any way to know if the robot we use in On/Off/Ready/ etc ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Any way to know if the robot we use in On/Off/Ready/ etc

ROS-Industrial compliant drivers will publish the [RobotStatus](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/industrial_msgs/html/msg/RobotStatus.html) message that should reflect the status of the controller/robot. From the documentation:

> The RobotStatus message contains low level status information that is specific to an industrial robot controller

Examples of fields in such messages: `mode`, `e_stopped`, `motion_possible`, `drives_powered` and `in_error`.

This only works with drivers that adhere to the [ROS-Industrial Driver Specification](http://wiki.ros.org/Industrial/Industrial_Robot_Driver_Spec). The drivers for the UR (both `ur_driver` and `ur_modern_driver`) nor the RSI component in `kuka_experimental` adhere to this, so they don't publish `RobotStatus` messages at this time.

That could be added. If you submit an enhancement request on the respective issue trackers it should receive attention.

> The second problem it implies is how to handles them ?

The specification does currently not provide a standardised interface to error handling functionality provided by robot controllers. That can be considered an omission (and it is), although remote error software reset functions/methods are certainly not ubiquitous in industrial controllers, which makes adding something like that to the specification somewhat difficult. `FAULT RESET` IOs (or similar, controllable via a fieldbus) are probably more generically present.

This could be a good discussion topic for the [ROS-Industrial mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/swri-ros-pkg-dev).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-10-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [matEhickey](https://answers.ros.org/users/31791/matehickey/) on 2017-10-12**:
Thank you for that quick response, too bad for me that these driver don't adhere as the specifications, I'll have a lot more work to do so.  Thank you again!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-12**:
No problem.

re: work: a nice way to approach this would be to extend those drivers such that they *do* publish `RobotState` messages. That means two relatively small extensions to the drivers, while you get to reuse your error handling and introspection code.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-12**:
And if you then submit PRs with those extensions to the repositories of the drivers, that would be `+3` :)

**Comment by [matEhickey](https://answers.ros.org/users/31791/matehickey/) on 2017-10-12**:
That what I was planning, hope I'll have time for all of this, I know well the UR, so it shouldn't be too long, but for the Kuka.. I'll give me a try :)